# Rails: delete cascade vs dependent destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, referential-integrity

Assuming I have two tables: `users` and `orders`. A user has many orders, so naturally there is a foreign key user_id in my orders table.

What is the best practice in rails (in terms of speed, style and referential integrity) to ensure that if a user is deleted, all dependent orders are also deleted? I am considering the following options:

Case 1. Using `:dependent => :destroy` in the user model

Case 2. Defining the table orders in postgres and writing

```
user_id integer REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Is there any reason why I should use Case 1? It seems that Case 2 is doing all I want it to do? Is there are difference in terms of execution speed?

Comment: Option 1 does not exclude option 2, you can have both. Option 2 is needed when you have multiple applications using the same database, where option 1 can be the better option for your rails application.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It really depends on the behavior you want. In case 1, destroy will be called on each associated order, and therefor so will the [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). In case 2, these callbacks are not triggered, but it will be way faster and guarantees referential integrity.

In an application's infancy, I'd recommend going with `:dependent => :destroy` because it lets you develop in a way that is independent of the database. Once you start to scale, you should start doing it in the database for performance/integrity reasons.

Comment: Peter, can't you use both at once? Like when you do `validate presence` on rails side and `null: false` on DB side for attrs?

Comment: I think you can but no one has yet answered my question about how they interact. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413592/what-does-rails-do-with-both-dependent-destroy-and-cascade-delete-nullify-r?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 29):

`has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy`

- Safest option for automatically maintaining data integrity.
- You have polymorphic associations, and do not want to use triggers.

`add_foreign_key :orders, :users, on_delete: :cascade` (in database migration)

- You are not using any polymorphic associations or you want to use triggers for each polymorphic association.

`has_many :orders, dependent: :delete_all`

- Only use when the has_many is a leaf node on your association tree (i.e. the child does not have another has_many association with foreign key references)

Comment: Hey Wiredln, how can I use this on_delete: :cascade in a polymorphic table? Is that possible?

Answer (score 8):

I would use option 1.  While it may work, I can see a number of issues with option 2:

1. ActiveRecord will be unaware that these records were deleted, which
   could lead to unstable behavior
2. it would be unclear to anyone reading the code that deleting a user means that all their orders will also be deleted
3. any `destroy` handlers on Order would not fire

Certainly I would expect option 2 to be faster, but it's up to you if the trade-offs are worth it.  Is deletion of a user a common operation in  your application?

Another option would be to use `:dependent => :delete_all`.  This would be faster than `:dependent => :destroy` and avoid drawbacks 1 and 2 above.  See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) for more details.