# Does rails delete method trigger a postgresql DELETE CASCADE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table called accounts that is extremely large ~600,000+. From this table, I need to delete about 1/3 of the accounts. On the accounts table are many references to different tables. What I want to do is to delete the accounts by batches to speed up the process but it looks like the Rails `delete` method does not do that.

So that is my question. Does the `delete` method trigger the `DELETE CASCADE` command? I tried it out on the rails console and it would seem that it in fact does not trigger a `DELETE CASCADE`. Is the only purpose of the `delete` method is to not trigger rails callbacks? Is there a different method that I can look into?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: delete cascade vs dependent destroy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556614/rails-delete-cascade-vs-dependent-destroy)

Answer (score 2):

There is not actually a Postgres command called `DELETE CASCADE`. But if you have foreign keys with the option `ON DELETE CASCADE`, then yes, when you delete a row, the rows that reference it will be deleted too. None of this is really Rails, but just Postgres.